# Why does git-bisect have to be run from the top level directory of the working tree?

Tags: git, git-bisect

If one tries to run any of the git-bisect commands from anywhere other than the root directory of the repository, one is told:

> You need to run this command from the toplevel of the working tree.

Why is that? I know of no other git command that has this requirement, and I see no obvious reason that bisect should be special. The man page makes no mention of this restriction, either.

It's really not a big deal. I'm mostly just curious.

Comment: I assume it's to make it clear that your whole working copy will be modified during the bisect

Comment: And to avoid the edge case of what to do if you're in a directory that gets removed. Then again, git doesn't track directories...

Comment: @CharlesB, Arafangion, Both those points apply just as much to git-checkout as they do to git-bisect, do they not?

Comment: @Arafangion it is true about any command changing wc - pull, merge, rebase, checkout, etc. Nothing special about bisect. I think it is just yet another misconception.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Looking at some commits in the project, I see one by Marcel M. Cary (marcel@oak.homeunix.org)

He says in a commit (it happens to be about git-pull but I think it is relevant)

> "git pull" fails because POSIX shells have a notion of current working
>   directory that is different from getcwd().  The shell stores this path
>   in PWD.  As a result, "cd ../" can be interpreted differently in a
>   shell script than chdir("../") in a C program.  The shell interprets
>   "../" by essentially stripping the last textual path component from
>   PWD, whereas C chdir() follows the ".." link in the current directory
>   on the filesystem.  When PWD is a symlink, these are different
>   destinations.  As a result, Git's C commands find the correct
>   top-level working tree, and shell scripts do not.
>
> https://github.com/git/git/commit/08fc0608657ee91bc85276667804c36a93138c7d

SO I'd say part of the reason is because git-bisect is a shell script which can't be trusted to find the toplevel on its own (when symlinks are involved).

Comment: I was hoping for a better reason, but that's hardly your fault. Thank you very much for doing some research.

Comment: Yeah a bit disappointing. Go ahead and dig in to the code; it's remarkably (and sometimes humorously) well-commented and the commit messages are excellent.

Answer (score 12):

The bisecting process needs to check out different revisions of your project. If a particular revision does not contain the current folder, then the current folder will be removed.

In that case, your shell could end up sitting in a folder which is no longer on the filesystem! Git will then be unable to find the toplevel's `.git` folder and so the bisect process cannot continue without intervention.

A demonstration:

```
$ git rev-parse --show-toplevel
/path/to/project
$ mkdir tmp
$ cd tmp
$ rmdir ../tmp
$ git rev-parse --show-toplevel
fatal: Unable to read current working directory: No such file or directory
```

Of course this same problem can occur when doing `git checkout`, and it can be easily fixed after the fact, e.g. with `cd ..` (willoller explains why that works in the shell but not in git).

But since bisecting is a *process* it makes sense to avoid this situation before we begin, especially if we want to use automation such as `git bisect run`.

Answer (score 9):

> As a result, Git's C commands find the correct top-level working tree, and shell scripts do not.

Well, with Git 2.21 (Feb. 2019), **[`git bisect`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect)** continues its transition from a shell script to C.

See [commit 06f5608](https://github.com/git/git/commit/06f5608c14e6972748b84649d5b8ffd335bbd209), [commit 450ebb7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/450ebb7359ec379a282670e85536540734c45eed), [commit 129a6cf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/129a6cf344c4b352433f5a24de02a62783f6c6df), [commit 4fbdbd5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4fbdbd5bfff874330115f8d7556cf7c9f7f138c9), [commit e3b1e3b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e3b1e3bdc0aa5fa6a474874a2395ae0584b2aea7), [commit 0f30233](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0f30233a11f6d89fb387ddf96db64877adb90713), [commit 5e82c3d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e82c3dd22aa804ba0ae571bf903b387b0f766a6) (02 Jan 2019) by [Pranit Bauva (`pranitbauva1997`)](https://github.com/pranitbauva1997).
Helped-by: [Ramsay Jones (`jeffhostetler`)](https://github.com/jeffhostetler), and [Stephan Beyer (`sbeyer`)](https://github.com/sbeyer).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 09a9c1f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/09a9c1f427c110f1281eea55c48596c8c8701a13), 07 Feb 2019)</sup>

> ### bisect--helper: `bisect_start` shell function partially in C

> Reimplement the `bisect_start` shell function partially in C and add
> `bisect-start` subcommand to `git bisect--helper` to call it from
> git-bisect.sh .
>
> This is not yet complete, but a side-effect of that migration will be the ability to execute `git bisect` from a subfolder.

---

Git 2.23 further improves that conversion to C.
See [commit 7877ac3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7877ac3d7b8ae84981c9c2fa86a4f3701ade4510) (21 May 2019) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5b476dc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5b476dc2f13324852d0dbf7f2e5c020d1064ac8c), 17 Jun 2019)</sup>

---

With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), `bisect_reset` benefits from a fix.

See [commit 51a0a4e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/51a0a4ed9597e949930d92be59f42f991bc40a7c) (09 Dec 2019) by [Tanushree Tumane (`tanushree27`)](https://github.com/tanushree27).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4bfc9cc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4bfc9ccfb6917805a4e1605bad359270172d145b), 25 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`bisect--helper`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/51a0a4ed9597e949930d92be59f42f991bc40a7c): avoid use-after-free
>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Christian Couder</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Tanushree Tumane</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Miriam Rubio</sup>

> In [5e82c3dd22a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e82c3dd22aa804ba0ae571bf903b387b0f766a6) ("`bisect--helper`: `bisect_reset` shell function in C", 2019-01-02, Git v2.21.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/09a9c1f427c110f1281eea55c48596c8c8701a13)), the `[`git bisect`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) reset` subcommand was ported to C.
> When the call to `git checkout` failed, an error message (`could not check out original HEAD`) was reported to the user.
>
> However, this error message used the `strbuf` that had just been released already.
> Let's switch that around: first use it, then release it.

---

That continues with Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), where the underlying machinery of "`git bisect--helper`" is being refactored into pieces that are more easily reused.

See [commit 6c69f22](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6c69f2223394c200cce1289ac9200f781ef14da7), [commit 9ec598e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ec598e0d55ff263e47d95e7d4decef1eb1b6ac6), [commit 45b6370](https://github.com/git/git/commit/45b6370812cb9bc50212d50f071c8ae5dd851698), [commit cdd4dc2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cdd4dc2d6a3e420178100efc780a987495a1a3bd), [commit e8e3ce6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e8e3ce67185fd493a07d84a5ce21b469701f8f64), [commit ce58b5d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ce58b5d8b128568e9b4f37703377cbc22eaf00f5), [commit 7613ec5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7613ec594a3cb3a5b67bd4f363a557374e744dfb) (17 Feb 2020) by [Pranit Bauva (`pranitbauva1997`)](https://github.com/pranitbauva1997).
See [commit 680e8a0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/680e8a01e57cd383048bf4e7d9668ce715d6d649), [commit b8e3b2f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b8e3b2f33994de25c068021e388dbef72a2cdc4a), [commit 16538bf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/16538bfd2c429a81a86011f32afa189047afd6e5) (17 Feb 2020) by [Miriam Rubio (``)](https://github.com/).
See [commit bfacfce](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bfacfce7d94951fe5b4e70bc2431dae5506b474b), [commit 292731c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/292731c4c24bce5c9e3bdc7a246cfbc565ab93a1) (17 Feb 2020) by [Tanushree Tumane (`tanushree27`)](https://github.com/tanushree27).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 25063e2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/25063e2530e2fbdccf5d372a8ad80309421c9df1), 05 Mar 2020)</sup>

For instance:

> ### [`bisect--helper`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bfacfce7d94951fe5b4e70bc2431dae5506b474b): introduce new `decide_next()` function
>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Christian Couder</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Tanushree Tumane</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Miriam Rubio</sup>

> Let's refactor code from `bisect_next_check()` into a new `decide_next()` helper function.
>
> This removes some `goto` statements and makes the code simpler, clearer and easier to understand.

---

Before Git 2.28 (Q3 2020), the code to parse "[`git bisect start`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) " command line was lax in validating the arguments.

See [commit 4d9005f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d9005ff5d1de0b4e82402320aab4ff27aa23b43) (20 May 2020) by [Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón (`carenas`)](https://github.com/carenas).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 63e50b8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/63e50b8678cbf9a9fd8c875d1f66f2f1a3d29088), 09 Jun 2020)</sup>

> ### [`bisect--helper`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d9005ff5d1de0b4e82402320aab4ff27aa23b43): avoid segfault with bad syntax in `start --term-*`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Christian Couder</sup>

> [06f5608c14](https://github.com/git/git/commit/06f5608c14e6972748b84649d5b8ffd335bbd209) ("`bisect--helper`: `bisect_start` shell function partially in C", 2019-01-02, Git v2.21.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/09a9c1f427c110f1281eea55c48596c8c8701a13)) adds a lax parser for `[`git bisect start`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect)` which could result in a segfault under a bad syntax call for start with custom terms.
>
> Detect if there are enough arguments left in the command line to use for `--term-{old,good,new,bad}` and abort with the same syntax error the original implementation will show if not.

---

Before Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), "[`git bisect  start X Y`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/03a01824a4ee07cd06b152bbff45066d6cf5542b/Documentation/git-bisect.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect))</sup>, when X and Y are not valid committish object names, should take X and Y as pathspec, but didn't.

See [commit 73c6de0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/73c6de06aff8d14b5e9f55f393d25f1213f3d43d) (25 Sep 2020) by [Christian Couder (`chriscool`)](https://github.com/chriscool).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 03a0182](https://github.com/git/git/commit/03a01824a4ee07cd06b152bbff45066d6cf5542b), 04 Oct 2020)</sup>

> ### [`bisect`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/73c6de06aff8d14b5e9f55f393d25f1213f3d43d): don't use invalid oid as rev when starting
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Christian Couder</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> In [06f5608c14](https://github.com/git/git/commit/06f5608c14e6972748b84649d5b8ffd335bbd209) ("`bisect--helper`: `bisect_start` shell function partially in C", 2019-01-02, Git v2.21.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/09a9c1f427c110f1281eea55c48596c8c8701a13)), we changed the following shell code:
>
> ```c
> -      rev=$(git rev-parse -q --verify "$arg^{commit}") || {
> -              test $has_double_dash -eq 1 &&
> -              die "$(eval_gettext "'\$arg' does not appear to be a valid revision")"
> -              break
> -      }
> -      revs="$revs $rev"
> ```
>
> into:
>
> ```c
> +      char *commit_id = xstrfmt("%s^{commit}", arg);
> +      if (get_oid(commit_id, &oid) && has_double_dash)
> +              die(_("'%s' does not appear to be a valid "
> +                    "revision"), arg);
> +
> +      string_list_append(&revs, oid_to_hex(&oid));
> +      free(commit_id);
> ```
>
> In case of an invalid "`arg`" when `"has_double_dash"` is false, the old code would "break" out of the argument loop.
>
> In the new C code though, `oid_to_hex(&oid)` is unconditonally appended to "`revs`". This is wrong first because "`oid`" is junk as `get_oid(commit_id, &oid)` failed, and second because it doesn't break out of the argument loop.
>
> Not breaking out of the argument loop means that "`arg`" is then not treated as a path restriction (which is wrong).

---

With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), the rewrite of the "[`git bisect`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f4cc68cbd078d5c0dd707384c802510261c67a28/Documentation/git-bisect.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect))</sup> script in C continues.

See [commit 517ecb3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/517ecb3161daa4503f7638489fd44177b3659913), [commit 09535f0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/09535f056b08445e28c4881064b8435fb434d760) (24 Sep 2020) by [Pranit Bauva (`pranitbauva1997`)](https://github.com/pranitbauva1997).
See [commit c7a7f48](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c7a7f48f4fe8319867ea025e55e930b48455652a) (24 Sep 2020), and [commit 7b4de74](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7b4de74b5de5c1ceb035d33168d482ad213b4137), [commit 3027676](https://github.com/git/git/commit/30276765c114bbd57ef0d8e6cf5489501599421a), [commit ef5aef5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ef5aef5ee0f8ff932f8beb21ff33a4dafee214b5) (28 Aug 2020) by [Miriam Rubio (`mirucam`)](https://github.com/mirucam).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f4cc68c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f4cc68cbd078d5c0dd707384c802510261c67a28), 04 Oct 2020)</sup>

> ### [`bisect--helper`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/517ecb3161daa4503f7638489fd44177b3659913): reimplement `bisect_next` and `bisect_auto_next` shell functions in C
>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Lars Schneider</sup>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Christian Couder</sup>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Pranit Bauva</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Tanushree Tumane</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Miriam Rubio</sup>

> Reimplement the `bisect_next()` and the `bisect_auto_next()` shell functions in C and add the subcommands to `[`git`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/517ecb3161daa4503f7638489fd44177b3659913/Documentation/git-.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-))</sup> bisect--helper` to call them from git-bisect.sh .
>
> `bisect_auto_next()` function returns an enum `bisect_error` type as whole `[`git bisect`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/517ecb3161daa4503f7638489fd44177b3659913/Documentation/git-bisect.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect))</sup>`  can exit with an error code when `bisect_next()` does.
>
> Return an error when `bisect_next()` fails, that fix a bug on shell script version.
>
> Using `--bisect-next` and `--bisect-auto-next` subcommands is a temporary measure to port shell function to C so as to use the existing test suite. As more functions are ported, `--bisect-auto-next` subcommand will be retired and will be called by some other methods.

---

With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), the rewriting "[`git bisect`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cfdc70b29935d3e7aa30d679e0076441f70a8ffe/Documentation/git-bisect.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect))</sup> in C continues.

See [commit b0f6494](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b0f6494f70fd72141581ae2d392d9d793be08b81), [commit 5c517fe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5c517fe345baa6bc7d0ecc31dd60c299dc6648ce), [commit 9b437b0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9b437b056d9b4c8c99fb1e9dfa0ad06072e2ab0f), [commit 27257bc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/27257bc4661ed7ffb715922693c7a2bee136824c), [commit 04774b4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/04774b4e7090e6b418ab053a6d4412a665cae703), [commit e439607](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e4396072e7b377ed4736e3fbd2b127e6e03da58c), [commit 88ad372](https://github.com/git/git/commit/88ad372fc02c119a4e44ae71c93b6fab9d998512) (15 Oct 2020) by [Pranit Bauva (`pranitbauva1997`)](https://github.com/pranitbauva1997).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit cfdc70b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cfdc70b29935d3e7aa30d679e0076441f70a8ffe), 09 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`bisect--helper`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/27257bc4661ed7ffb715922693c7a2bee136824c): reimplement `bisect_state` & `bisect_head` shell functions in C
>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Lars Schneider</sup>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Christian Couder</sup>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Pranit Bauva</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Tanushree Tumane</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Miriam Rubio</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> Reimplement the `bisect_state()` shell functions in C and also add a subcommand `--bisect-state` to `git-bisect--helper` to call them from `git-bisect.sh`.

---

With Git 2.31 (Q1 2021): piecemeal of rewrite of "[`git bisect`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0871fb9af5aa03a56c42a9257589248624d75eb8/Documentation/git-bisect.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect))</sup> in C continues.

See [commit 97b8294](https://github.com/git/git/commit/97b8294474f8995ad67d57dbae6d524523a9ec2a), [commit e4c7b33](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e4c7b33747dccc6600bc528b51e91c11b474eb04), [commit 9feea34](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9feea34810b750a6bca30ea82878fa2cbb0b830b), [commit b7a6f16](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b7a6f163d6273896e4f846f63dd711be0174522b), [commit 68efed8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/68efed8c8a43ad95f4e517ea60034179418dd8bc), [commit 2b1fd94](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2b1fd947f6d81ae772ebb75ef2e668866ab38c55), [commit 97d5ba6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/97d5ba6a39253a38229dd4518afd0410d13f615a) (03 Feb 2021) by [Pranit Bauva (`pranitbauva1997`)](https://github.com/pranitbauva1997).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0871fb9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0871fb9af5aa03a56c42a9257589248624d75eb8), 17 Feb 2021)</sup>

> ### [`bisect--helper`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/68efed8c8a43ad95f4e517ea60034179418dd8bc): retire `--bisect-write` subcommand
>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Lars Schneider</sup>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Christian Couder</sup>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Pranit Bauva</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Tanushree Tumane</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Miriam Rubio</sup>

> The `--bisect-write` subcommand is no longer used from the git-bisect.sh shell script.
> Instead the function `bisect_write()` is directly called from the C implementation.

---

"[`git bisect`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/35381b13da846cc6ad620f9f9a5abf1d974d6e9b/Documentation/git-bisect.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect))</sup> reimplemented more in C during 2.30 timeframe did not take an annotated tag as a good/bad endpoint well.
This regression has been corrected with Git 2.31.1 (Q1 2021).

See [commit 7730f85](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7730f85594d4595605934e39d1d816ab663d8fa8) (16 Mar 2021) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 35381b1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35381b13da846cc6ad620f9f9a5abf1d974d6e9b), 19 Mar 2021)</sup>

> ### [`bisect`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7730f85594d4595605934e39d1d816ab663d8fa8): peel annotated tags to commits
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> This patch fixes a bug where '[`git-bisect`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7730f85594d4595605934e39d1d816ab663d8fa8/Documentation/git-bisect.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect))</sup> doesnt handle receiving annotated tags as "`git bisect`" good `<tag>`, etc.
> It's a regression in [27257bc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/27257bc4661ed7ffb715922693c7a2bee136824c) ("`bisect--helper`: reimplement `bisect_state` & `bisect_head` shell functions in C", 2020-10-15, Git v2.30.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cfdc70b29935d3e7aa30d679e0076441f70a8ffe) listed in [batch #4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e4d83eee9239207622e2b1cc43967da5051c189c)).
>
> The original shell code called:
>
> ```
> sha=$(git rev-parse --verify "$rev^{commit}") ||
>         die "$(eval_gettext "Bad rev input: \$rev")"
> ```
>
> which will peel the input to a commit (or complain if that's not possible).
> But the C code just calls `get_oid()`, which will yield the oid of the tag.
>
> The fix is to peel to a commit.
> The error message here is a little non-idiomatic for Git (since it starts with a capital).

New error message:

```
Bad rev input (not a commit): xxxx
```

---

Warning: "[`git bisect skip`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8ca4771dd0889ce269780b5f2b48166ffaff9570/Documentation/git-bisect.txt#L257-L289)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect#_bisect_skip))</sup> when custom words are used for new/old did *not* work in Git 2.31, which has been corrected with Git 2.32 (Q2 2021).

See [commit 4cd66e7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4cd66e7d6b423d3c5b161b55afb07cb1df59e75f) (29 Apr 2021) by [Ramsay Jones (`ramsay-jones`)](https://github.com/ramsay-jones).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8ca4771](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8ca4771dd0889ce269780b5f2b48166ffaff9570), 11 May 2021)</sup>

> ### [`bisect--helper`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4cd66e7d6b423d3c5b161b55afb07cb1df59e75f): use `BISECT_TERMS` in '`bisect skip`' command
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Trygve Aaberge</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Bagas Sanjaya</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ramsay Jones</sup>

> Commit [e4c7b33](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e4c7b33747dccc6600bc528b51e91c11b474eb04) ("`bisect--helper`: reimplement `bisect_skip` shell function in C", 2021-02-03, Git v2.31.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0871fb9af5aa03a56c42a9257589248624d75eb8) listed in [batch #9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2283e0e9af55689215afa39c03beb2315ce18e83)), as part of the shell-to-C conversion, forgot to read the 'terms' file (`.git/BISECT_TERMS`) during the new '`bisect skip`' command implementation.
> As a result, the '`bisect skip`' command will use the default 'bad'/'good' terms.
> If the bisection terms have been set to non-default values (for example by the '`bisect start`' command), then the '`bisect skip`' command will fail.
>
> In order to correct this problem, we insert a call to the `get_terms()` function, which reads the non-default terms from that file (if set), in the '`--bisect-skip`' command implementation of '`bisect--helper`'.
>
> Also, add a [test](https://lore.kernel.org/git/xmqqim45h585.fsf@gitster.g/T/#m207791568054b0f8cf1a3942878ea36293273c7d) to protect against potential future regression.

---

With Git 2.33 (Q3 2021), "[`git bisect`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ae2d05d0c6b1834cfcfc5e060db6cf8d91160c5b/Documentation/git-bisect.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect))</sup> spawned [`git show-branch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ae2d05d0c6b1834cfcfc5e060db6cf8d91160c5b/Documentation/git-show-branch.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-branch))</sup> only to pretty-print the title of the commit after checking out the next version to be tested; this has been rewritten in C.

See [commit 1fcc40c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1fcc40cd1dbfbdf6879a7b60a3a0250e46dc5c60) (28 Jul 2021), and [commit ffcb4e9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ffcb4e94d309db2889dac1d3dcbd0f4b2a0f6390) (27 Jul 2021) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ae2d05d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ae2d05d0c6b1834cfcfc5e060db6cf8d91160c5b), 24 Aug 2021)</sup>

> ### [`bisect`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ffcb4e94d309db2889dac1d3dcbd0f4b2a0f6390): do not run show-branch just to show the current commit

> In scripted versions of "[`git bisect`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ffcb4e94d309db2889dac1d3dcbd0f4b2a0f6390/Documentation/git-bisect.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect))</sup>, we used "[`git show-branch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ffcb4e94d309db2889dac1d3dcbd0f4b2a0f6390/Documentation/git-show-branch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-branch))</sup> to describe a single commit in the bisect log and also to the interactive user after checking out the next version to be tested.
>
> The former use of "`git show-branch`" was lost when the helper function that wrote bisect log entries was rewritten at [0f30233](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0f30233a11f6d89fb387ddf96db64877adb90713) ("`bisect--helper`: `bisect_write` shell function in C", 2019-01-02, Git v2.21.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/09a9c1f427c110f1281eea55c48596c8c8701a13)) in C
>
> But we've kept the latter ever since [0871984](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0871984d304c9201b85897743eae583cd165106d) (`bisect`: make , 2009-05-09, Git v1.6.4-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d34f715853526bf55f1fa422d56608c32433c8d1)) (bisect: make "`git bisect`" use new `--next-all` bisect-helper function, 2009-05-09) started using the faithful C-rewrite introduced at [ef24c7c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ef24c7ca055f03c673c2b67a3a7c92bcc32f62f0) (`bisect--helper`: add , 2009-04-19, Git v1.6.4-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d34f715853526bf55f1fa422d56608c32433c8d1)) (`bisect--helper`: add "`--next-exit`" to output bisect results, 2009-04-19).
>
> Showing "`[<full hex>] <subject>`" is simple enough with our helper [`pretty.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ffcb4e94d309db2889dac1d3dcbd0f4b2a0f6390/pretty.c)::format_commit_message() and spawning show-branch is an overkill.
> Let's lose one external process.

Comment: Your dedication to keep updating this answer for newer Git versions is impressive!

Comment: @ParkerCoates Thank you. That rewrite in C is an effort which spans quite a few Git releases. (I did not contribute to it, I just report it here as it happens)